# Writing File to Google Cloud Store Bucket

Tags: r, opencpu

Just a quick question please guys - Could do with some help with the role of a user in the use of OpenCPU

Trying to run a small R script that copies a file from local to Google Cloud Store Bucket - consider a toy example

```
write.table(1:10, "/R/test.dat")
system(paste("gsutil cp /R/test.dat gs://my-bucket/", sample(1:100, 1), ".dat", sep = ""))
```

The file writes fine to local, but the copy fails - the bucket permissions fine for a user (runs in R on the server work fine), but i am confused as to the role of the user in a OpenCPU call - Does anyone know how to set the permissions to allow this copy please?

Comment: Can you add the actual error message or failure, that you are getting?